# Is it possible to add a custom part to Excel workbook

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add a custom Object (A Zip file) along with a [Custom XML part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx) to the Excel workbook. Our purpose is to process this zip file on workbook_open by an add-in installed on the machine. Is it possible to embed such a  binary custom object within a spreadsheet along with a custom XML part?

Any pointers are appreciated..